# Уменьшительные прозвища

Tags: этимология, лексика

Мы часто называем друг друга ласково "котик", "рыбка", "зайка". Интересно, почему именно эти животные? Ну, коты и зайцы пушистые и симпатичные, но рыбы мокрые и скользкие (хоть я рыб очень люблю), а кроме зайцев и котов множество других пушистых и милых зверей. А вот в Чехии, например, девушку ласково называют "жабка". Просто интересно, почему вообще ласково называют животными и по какому принципу выбирают?
А на вопрос меня натолкнула вот эта картинка:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо, потому что котята, рыбки, зайки вызывают такое же тёплое и нежное чувство, как и солнышко.Даже мышка и жабка.

Когда так называет мужчина, он демонстрирует своё мужское начало, силу, готовность сильного  защитить и приласкать слабое существо(женщины любят ушами, т.е. любят, когда их называют нежно и ласково), когда женщина детей - показывает своё материнское желание защитить ребёнка, когда женщина  мужчину -она  демонстрирует женскую теплоту, заботу, желание обогреть, приблизить к себе. В любом случае это - выражение близости почти на бессознательном уровне. Правда, мне это никогда не нравилось, меня звали по имени, и я всех звала по имени, правда, иногда ласково.